# C++ How do I pause the console output so that the user can read info before continuing

Tags: c++, console, pause

I have been looking for a way to pause the console display.  I found some suggestions out on the internet but it's not working the way I'd like it to.

My Question: How can I improve this pause() function to recognize any key (including the enter key)?

---

I'll tell you what happened first and then show you the snippet of code.

1. I found some helpful way to pause the screen I wrote a small pause() function and called it in my mainline
2. The function puts out a line "Press any key to continue..."
3. I ran the program and the line was put to the screen but did not pause
4. Thinking that something was in the input buffer and it was being pulled off I added a line to display the hex value of the 1st character of the line.
5. What displayed was not in hex (bummers) but it did show that my output display line split.  So I think it is an end-of-line character (I removed that line to display in hex because it was not working as I wanted it to)
   I have updated the function and it now displays the hex character and the character is x'0a' (Line Feed)
6. So I added a line to pull that end-of-line character before issuing the cin.get() to pause the screen
7. That worked.  Console was paused
8. I hit the ENTER key and the input was taken but the program did not resume
9. I then hit the 'x' letter key and the program resumed
10. BUT .. the logic in pause() was supposed to throw an error.  It did not. The test for 'x' did not work.

    11. The value after I hit the 'x' key is actually a line feed (x'0a')

Here is the code:

```
    #ifndef MYFUNCTIONS
    #define MYFUNCTIONS

    #include <cstdio>
    #include <cstdlib>

    using std::cout;
    using std::cin;

    void pause() {
    string holdit;
    //std::cout.flush();
    //std::cin.clear();
    std::cout << std::endl << "Press any key to continue...";
    std::cin >> holdit;
    holdit = std::cin.get();
    std::cout << "The first character in holdit is <" << holdit[0] << "> x'" << setfill('0') << setw(2) << std::hex << (int)holdit[0] << "'" << endl;
    if (holdit[0] == 'x') throw 99;
}

    #endif
```

Thanks, in advance, for your help.

Comment: One question per stackoverflow.com question, please.

Comment: To output a value in hex, you can use `<< std::hex` before outputting the value. However I believe `char`-typed values are still output as characters and not as numbers, so you can convert them to an `int`: `<< std::hex << (int)holdit[0]`

Comment: "put in to get the eol char that is there (why it's there I don't know)" - It's left there by your previous input operations.

Answer (score 0):

After quite a few attempts at creating a pause() function, I have it.  It recognizes the ENTER key as well as any other key.  The function includes a cout statement to display the 1st character in hex (which I used during my debugging).  If you have any comments, please let me know.  I'm a beginner at C++.  So be kind :)  Thanks.

```
#ifndef MYFUNCTIONS
#define MYFUNCTIONS

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

void pause()
{
    char holdit;

    cout << "Press any key to continue..." << endl;
    holdit = _getch();
    cout << "holdit = < x'" << setfill('0') << setw(2) << hex << (int)holdit << "'>" << dec << endl;
    if (holdit == 'x') throw 99;

}

#endif
```